# Dex not working with spaces in path on the new android platform tools (V8)

Tags: android, ant

On the new android platform tools (v8) released with the 2.3 SDK, I get an error while running dex from the ant script

I typed the usual "ant release", and got an error in the dex stage

```
-dex:
    [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Documents and Settings\omri\My Documents\myapp\bin\classes.dex...
   [apply] =C:\Documents was unexpected at this time.
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the spaces in the path.
anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: did u try eclosing the path in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem it appears to be with the spaces in the path as you guessed.
If you specify the path using 8.3 names there will be no spaces and dex will work.

For the path above the 8.3 path would be similar to below:

> C:\Docume~1\omri\MyDocu~1\myapp\bin

You can use dir /X to find the 8.3 name of a file or folder.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I also thought about that, but this means you you set the absolute path for out.dir right, not a relative path. it works, but I'd rather not do this so I can still build on multiple machines (If no better solution will be given I will go your way. thanks!)

Comment: I don't specify out.dir and it outputs to the default directoy which appears to be the equivalent of 'C:\Docume~1\omri\MyDocu~1\myapp\output'

Comment: so where did you specify the path?

Comment: I have the android client compiling as part of an automatic build so I set the working directory to 'C:\Docume~1\omri\MyDocu~1\myapp\'.  It automatically picks up your current working directory.

If your running from the command line it's the same as changing the directory to 'C:\Docume~1\omri\MyDocu~1\myapp\' and then running 'ant release'

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, there is another way of dealing with this - in fact, the batch file for `dex` is at fault! I discovered the fix for it in a [blog](http://june-takeout.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-my-tip-android-ant-release.html) here.

Basically look for the lines within the `dex.bat` around line 49 or thereabouts

```
REM capture all arguments to process them below 
set params=%*

:nextArg  
if "%params%"=="" goto endArgs
```

Insert this sequence of code in between

```
REM capture all arguments to process them below
set params=%*

echo ***** SKIP check the parameter *****
set args=%params%
goto endArgs

:nextArg
if "%params%"=="" goto endArgs
```

After that, you should save and rebuild with ANT, now it should work, it works around the fact that the command does not parse duplicated double-quotes.

Comment: I wish I could give 10 "ups" for this solution. IT WORKS